# How to load an image from URL in app Extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, today-extension

I have implemented an app extension for my application, but i am facing an issue when trying to load an image from a URL into an imageView.
I tried to use PAImageView and UIImageView but both with failure.

The code that i was using for PAImageView is the following:

```
[self.imageView setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://blabblaLogo.jpg"]];
          self.userImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

and tried to use SDWebImage for UIImageView with the following:

```
 [self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
        }];
```

and the image doesnt appear in both cases. Note that a default image from assets is displayed correctly without any issue.

Is it possible to load an image from a URL in an app Extension? and how can we achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: provide actual image URL...

Comment: i have already a valid url..just putted https://blabblaLogo.jpg for the post

Comment: try `imageView setImage` instead of `self.imageView`

Comment: Same Result..it works on default image from assets but not from URL .. this only is happening on the app Extension

Comment: is image on server big? what is size of image? may be loading is taking time...

Comment: No, it is just a thumbnail of 4Kb size

Comment: did you tried to load an image from a url in app extension?

Comment: not yet... i never did app extension

Comment: The problem is only occurring on app extension. I am not facing any issue in the containing app.

Comment: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/859 I think there is problem with app extension

Comment: I have already solved the issue of sharedApplication mentioned in your link.
you can help them by adding the following: Go to the app extension settings -> Build Settings then search for Preprocessor Macros and add TARGET_IS_EXTENSION value for it. Then add  #ifndef TARGET_IS_EXTENSION // here should be the uiapplication Sharedapplication #endif  to wherever UIApplication shared application exists in these classes

Comment: so your problem solved? if yes, post answer and mark it accepted...

Comment: No, my problem is not with Sharedapplication, my previous answer was to the people who are asking for using the SDWebImage or ASIHttpRequest to use any hit request in app Extension from your link github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/859 . I sent it to you in case you want to help them because i don't have a gitHub account...My problem of downloading the image is still existing.. I cant download any image from URL

Comment: anyone able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Am using something like this and it's work good until this issues fixed

cell.avatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selection-box_emty.png"];

```
// Load the image with an GCD block executed in another thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Arr[indexPath.row][@"avatar"]]];

    if (data) {
        UIImage *offersImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        if (offersImage) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                UIImage *offersImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                cell.avatar.image = offersImage;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, put breakpoints into into library and problem apparently was **App Tranport Security**. We need separate App Transport Security Settings for every extension we add

Answer (score 0):

Try This in your Image url

If image url contain any space it will add `%20` and work fine

```
[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```